# Prove this function defined by a matrix is a vector norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $|||\cdot|||$ is a vector norm on  $\mathbb{R}^m$ and that $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix having rank $n$.Prove $|||\mathbf{x}|||$ defined by $$|||\mathbf{x}|||=||\mathbf{Ax}||$$ 
is a vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note: this is a direct replica of a question in book "Applied Linear Algebra" by Ben Noble and James Daniel

Comment: It is unlikely that your replication of a question in a book will by itself inspire Readers to think that you are much invested in finding an Answer to this problem.  Please share your own thoughts about an approach and what difficulties attach to that approach.

Comment: @hardmath thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 4):

Norms must:

- Always be positive if element is nonzero  ($x\neq 0\Rightarrow \|\!|x|\!\|>0$)
- Always be zero if element is zero ($\|\!|0|\!\|=0$)
- Satisfy the triangle inequality ($\|\!|x+y|\!\|\leq \|\!|x|\!\|+\|\!|y|\!\|$)
- Scalar multiplication can be pulled outside ($\|\!|\alpha x|\!\|=|\alpha|\|\!|x|\!\|$)

For the first, note that since $A$ is rank $n$, you have $\ker(A)=\{0\}$ and so when $x\neq 0$ you have $Ax\neq 0$.  Since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, you have $\|\!|x|\!\|=\|Ax\|>0$.

For the second, again, remembering that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, you have $\|\!|0|\!\|=\|A0\|=\|0\|=0$.

For the third and fourth, remember that matrices act as linear transformations and so $\|\!|\alpha x+y|\!\|=\|A(\alpha x+y)\|=\|\alpha Ax + Ay\|$ and since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm, this is $\leq |\alpha|\|Ax\|+\|Ay\|=|\alpha|\|\!|x|\!\|+\|\!|y|\!\|$